# Searching using google and python and storing the first link?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, google-search

I am trying to make use of google search and get the first URL from the search results. I tried to make use of the `google custom search api`. But it seems over the top for such a simple task. Hence, I am trying to use this interesting package I found: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google

This is what I came up with so far

```
from google import search
url = search('my search entry', stop=1)
for result in url:
    print(url)
```

It seems that `search()` returns several generator objects. This is my return:

```
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
<generator object search at 0x10e230048>
```

However, I want the first external url/link. Is there a way to do that? I tried `list()` - but the `generator` seems empty.

Comment: if you don't find a way to do this using this library try using selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://pythonhosted.org/google/ , the signature of search is

```
generator search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0)
```

Try setting num = 1 and stop = 0.

Comment: Thanks, that already helps me! But the result ist still `<generator object search at 0x10e230048>` - which is better. Albeit, how do I get my hands on the acctual URL?

Comment: From the same link:  Returns: generator
    Generator (iterator) that yields found URLs. If the stop parameter is None the iterator will loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Selenium` as mentioned by [gabriel belini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3586954/gabriel-belini). Here is the code that I wrote just a while now for this

```
  from selenium import webdriver
  import time
  chrome_path ="/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/chromedriver"

  driver =webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

  driver.get('https://google.com')


  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input#lst-ib.gsfi').send_keys('Music')

 time.sleep(5)

 driver.find_element_by_name('btnG').click()

 time.sleep(3)

 element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rso']/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/cite")

 print(element1.text)
```

which outputs -> `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-9-kyTW8ZkZNDHQJ6FgpwQ`

If I search for `Music` keyword in search box, the first result returned is of Youtube - you can see this here

[image]

You can use `pip` to install `Selenium` as

```
  pip install -U Selenium
```

and download `chromedriver` from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/). This `chrome_path` in above script is the path where you will keep your `chromedriver` executable.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution. However using http://pythonhosted.org/google/ is much much quicker, so I opted for it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) web scraping library if you don't want to use either Google API or browser automation such as `selenium`  which slows the scraping process a bunch.

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/google-search-find-first-link#main.py)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

# this URL params is taken from the actual Google search URL
# and transformed to a more readable format
params = {
  "q": "music",                               # query
  "gl": "us",                                 # country to search from
  "hl": "en",                                 # language
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

website_link = soup.select_one(".yuRUbf a")["href"]
print(website_link)
```

Example output

```
https://music.youtube.com/
```

More info about [what CSS selectors are](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#explanation), and the [cons of using CSS selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#css_cons).